# C# Datagridview column values compare

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a datagridview contains many parameters 
for example:
column 1 
12
100
2349
3600
7000

my question is how do i create some loop to compare between values (from start or from end of the column) in order to find if the difference between them is less than 100.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: What kind of dataset or table do you have? Give more details.

Comment: i don't wanna run this function on a dataset or table...

Answer (score 0):

Comparing datagridview values are one of important subject of its field. You can compare them with their specific row and column.

First of all you need to determine which rows and columns are you going to compare.

You can [Read](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/455989/how-to-compare-cell-values-of-datagridview-with-each-other)  this article for comparing datagridview values.

Comment: hi i still do not understand how can i run the function of comparing one column (in the [0] location) values.

Comment: @GiladBronshtein comparing datagridview is simple. Try to read the article which i mentioned, then you will understand.